# React - Update controlled element that has a default value

Tags: reactjs

I've been looking all over but I can't seem to find silver bullet solution to this question.

In my app I can create a note. I want to be able to edit/update the note. The value of the note is passed down via props. How do I use props to as the default value of the textarea but also keep track of the new value of the note?

```
class Note extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      noteValue: ''
    };

    this.saveNote = this.saveNote.bind(this);
    this.updateNote = this.updateNote.bind(this);
  }

  saveNote() {
    // Saves the note
  }

  updateNote(e) {
    this.setState({ noteValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('ALREADY CREATED NOTE VALUE : ', this.props.note.value)
    return (
      <textarea
        // defaultValue={this.props.note.value} I want to be able to do this but I know I can't since it's controlled
        onChange={this.updateNote}
        value={this.state.noteValue}
      />
      <button onClick={this.saveNote}>Save</button>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    updateNote: NoteActions.updateNote,
  }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    note: NoteSelectors.getNoteById(state, props)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Note);
```

What is the best way to update a field/input when it has a defaultValue via props?

1. Doing `this.state = { ...this.props }` in the constructor doesn't seem to be the right way. All articles say it's an anti pattern.
2. I'm really confused on using `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle method exactly for the situation. It listens all changes of props of the your component. And it will be triggered for each props change. And still you should check the your new needed props in the lifecycle method to don't re-render unnecessarily.

return value works as `setState` function of React. It changes of state of your component immediately.

```
class Note extends Component
{
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, currentState)
  {
    console.log(newProps); // also you can listen the changes for simple debugging

    if (newProps.noteValue !== currentState.noteValue)
    {
      return ({ noteValue: newProps.noteValue }); // it will make change the state with new prop value
    }

    return null; // if nothing changed
  }

....
}
```

Comment: It seems with this situation that I would have to be updating my note (which is pulling from the redux store) as soon as the user begins to type in the textarea. I don't want to update anything until they hit save. Instead, I want their updates to be tracked in state. Listening to props won't do me any good because it should remain the same until I send off the API call to update the note.

Comment: Use two state variable which are defaultNote and currentNote. You are going to update only the local state as currentNote variable. And when they save the note then  they trigger redux state and you will get the new state as defaultNote from `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: When I type in textarea, it will update `this.state.noteValue`. This will cause your `if` statement in `getDerivedStateFromProps` to fire. Thus, the value will always be the value from props and the textarea text will never change.

Comment: I made a simple solution. I hope it helps. https://codepen.io/trdunya/pen/qemawQ?editors=0011

Comment: In your solution you are setting state.value equal to props in the constructor which is an anti pattern `this.state = { value: this.props.defaultValue } `

Comment: I don't think so but I wonder, where did you read that it's anti-pattern? And what's the its wrong side effects? Already, job of `static getDerivedStateFromProps` life cycle method is transfer **prop** to **state**.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. After reviewing a few things, this is the right answer.

Comment: I hope that answer have helped you. I think that is the only way to avoid the anti-pattern if to use carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `componentDidMount` method,

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({ noteValue : this.props.note.value})
}
```

When component finishes loading you can set `noteValue` to the value from `props`, in this case you don't need to set `defaultValue` instead your `value` attribute will work.

While updating, you can make use of `callback` in `setState` to send updated value to parent component

```
updateNote(e) {
    this.setState({ noteValue: e.target.value }, () => //call function from parent to update the change);
}
```

Comment: I also saw this method but it will always cause a second render on first load. At that point I'd rather just set it in the constructor to avoid the extra render.

Comment: Setting props to state in constructor might take you to the issue of undefined props, because by the time props are ready (considering data from API call), your constructor  from child may get execute first.

Comment: Yeah I definitely ran into that issue and had to use a ternary to check for the data. Not happy with my current solution but just moving on a little while I continue to look.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with another solution by doing:

```
this.state = {
  noteValue: ''
};

....

<textarea
  onChange={this.updateNote}
  value={this.state.noteValue || this.props.note.value || ''}
/>
```

Since empty string is falsy (`this.state.noteValue`) it will go to `this.props.note.value` first, if that doesn't exist, it will end with empty string.